How do I set cookies in Micronaut Reactive Controllers
I have these service methods which return Monos, and I'm trying to set the cookies with them. This doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do this?
I need this to return HttpResponse<Mono> and using block() results in an error saying java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread default-nioEventLoopGroup-2-4
      @Post
      public Mono<HttpResponse<Mono<UserDto>>> login(@Body LoginDto loginDto, @Header(value = "User-Agent") String userAgentStr,
                                                     @CookieValue(value = "myapp-auth-deviceId") UUID deviceId) {
        return registrationService.login(loginDto)
            .flatMap(user -> {
              MutableHttpResponse<Mono<UserDto>> httpResponse = HttpResponse.ok(Mono.just(user));
              return registrationService.registerDevice(userAgentStr, deviceId, user)
                  .flatMap(device -> registrationService.getJwtToken(user, device))
                  .flatMap(jwtToken -> {
                    httpResponse.cookie(Cookie.of(DEVICE_ID_COOKIE_NAME, deviceId.toString()).path("/").maxAge(365 * 24 * 3600));
                    httpResponse.cookie(Cookie.of(AUTH_COOKIE_NAME, jwtToken).maxAge(365 * 24 * 3600));
                    return Mono.just((HttpResponse<Mono<UserDto>>) httpResponse);
                  });
            }).single();
      }




import required class:
-->cookie to respond a cookie.
-->HttpResponse to send a response that includes the cookie.

2.Set the cookie:
-->Use the HttpResponse.cookie()method to create a respone with cookie.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Figured it out.
    MutableHttpResponse<Mono<UserDto>> httpResponse = HttpResponse.ok();
    UUID finalDeviceId = deviceId;
    return httpResponse.body(registrationService.login(loginDto)
        .flatMap(user -> registrationService.registerDevice(userAgentStr, finalDeviceId, user)
            .flatMap(device -> registrationService.getJwtToken(user, device))
            .map(jwtToken -> {
              httpResponse.cookie(Cookie.of(DEVICE_ID_COOKIE_NAME, finalDeviceId.toString()).path("/").maxAge(365 * 24 * 3600));
              httpResponse.cookie(Cookie.of(AUTH_COOKIE_NAME, jwtToken).path("/").maxAge(365 * 24 * 3600));
              return user;
            })));

This way it is waiting for the body, while I'm populating the cookies. The body is resolved after the cookies are populated.
